# Limit number of running virtual machines in ESXI

Tags: vmware-esxi

Is there a way to limit the maximum number of VM's that are running at one time in ESXI?

From empirical evidence it seems our server can only handle about 20 so I'd like to prevent users from starting more VM's when we reach that number.

Comment: This seems a bit like an XY problem to me.

Comment: What is your capacity planning process? What resource are you actually limited on? Have you considered resource reservations to enforce a minimum on VMs?

Comment: Disk I/O ends up being the problem. It looks like resource reservation might be able to guide me down a path.

Answer (score 3):

This might be something you are looking for: https://kb.vmware.com/s/article/2032825

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Comment: That sets VMs registered to a host, not how many can be started.